# Can not run "Percona XtraDB Cluster 5.7" on Centos 7

Tags: mysql, percona

I want used "Percona XtraDB Cluster 5.7".
So I installed "Percona XtraDB Cluster" by official guide.
https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/5.7/install/yum.html#yum
But when I add nodes to cluster, my mysql coudn't run.

```
$ sudo service mysql start
Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

$ sudo cat /var/log/messages
...
Jan 13 04:19:25 localhost mysqld_safe: 2017-01-12T19:19:25.588436Z mysqld_safe Skipping wsrep-recover for empty datadir: /var/lib/mysql
Jan 13 04:19:25 localhost mysqld_safe: 2017-01-12T19:19:25.590385Z mysqld_safe Assigning 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1 to wsrep_start_position
Jan 13 04:19:27 localhost mysql-systemd: State transfer in progress, setting sleep higher
Jan 13 04:19:40 localhost mysqld_safe: 2017-01-12T19:19:40.723030Z mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
Jan 13 04:19:47 localhost mysql-systemd: /usr/bin/mysql-systemd: 137 行: kill: (19791) - そのようなプロセスはありません
Jan 13 04:19:47 localhost mysql-systemd: ERROR! mysqld_safe with PID 19791 has already exited: FAILURE
Jan 13 04:19:47 localhost systemd: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 13 04:19:47 localhost mysql-systemd: WARNING: mysql pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid empty or not readable
Jan 13 04:19:47 localhost mysql-systemd: ERROR! mysql already dead
Jan 13 04:19:47 localhost systemd: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=2
...
```

I used centos7 on 3 virtual machine.
And my `/etc/my.cnf` is default except following code.

```
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera3/libgalera_smm.so

wsrep_cluster_name=pxc-cluster
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.70.61,192.168.70.62,192.168.70.63

wsrep_node_name=pxc1
wsrep_node_address=192.168.70.61

wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup-v2
wsrep_sst_auth=sstuser:passw0rd

pxc_strict_mode=ENFORCING

binlog_format=ROW
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
```

What should I check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first node, you should bootstrap it, instead of just starting it. On CentOS7 you can do so with:

`systemctl start mysql@bootstrap.service`

Then, you can go ahead and start nodes 02 and 03 normally:

`systemctl start mysql`

Comment: This is correct. You must bootstrap the first node of any cluster from an "all down" state. Even if it is a clean down state, you must bootstrap the first node. The other nodes can start normally.